# Install Azure Sign Tool to local path

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I have a step in a simple yaml pipeline to install the Azure Sign Tool.
It installs it here but I do not have access /home/vsts/work/1/s.
Is there any way I can install the Azure Sign Tool to my local.

Maybe add a local path variable EF_BUILD_REPOSITORY_LOCAL and set it to my C:\temp folder?? Would that work?

```
 - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
   inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    custom: 'tool'
    arguments: 'install azuresigntool --tool-path $($env:EF_BUILD_REPOSITORY_LOCALPATH) -v diag'
  displayName: Install AzureSignTool
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you install the tool in order to use it in the subsequent steps of the pipeline. In this case, you can try installing it globally:

```
dotnet tool install --global AzureSignTool
```

In this case, you don't have to specify the tool path, and you can use it by specifying just the name later:

```
AzureSignTool sign ...
```

Comment: The Sign Tool installs fine but when I use AzureSignTool sign -du ......, I get the following error /home/vsts/work/_temp/c40ffce1-6c7e-4a22-8394-44fbe6569242.sh: line 1: AzureSignTool: command not found
Any idea what this means?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like as the following steps.

```yaml
steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk'
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Install AzureSignTool'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: tool
    arguments: 'install -g azuresigntool -v diag'
```

In addition, it seems that Azure Sign Tool is only supported on Windows. We could install the tool on Linux or macOS, but not use it.

Comment: Hi @Bright Ran-MSFT, The SignTool installs fine but when I go to run a sign command, with AzureSignTool sign -du ................ I get the following error - /home/vsts/work/_temp/38d49f87-9800-456b-9c71-e507b6593382.sh: line 1: AzureSignTool: command not found
Is there any way around this? 
In the install sign tool step,The BUILD_REPOSITORY_LOCALPATH = /home/vsts/work/1/s